# SQL Server: localhost vs MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-localdb

I have two different local versions of SQL Server on my machine:

1. (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
2. localhost

[image: Local SQL Servers]

I think one of them might have been installed alongside Visual Studio, but I am not sure. Is there a difference between these two (other than the version number)?

And if I only want to keep one of them, which one should it be? I am only using it for local stuff, while developing...

Answer (score 3):

LocalDB is installed by Visual Studio and is intended to be minimal configuration for development work.  Check out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you want to keep just one, I'd go for SQL Express as you can easily connect to there for your development work.

Comment: SQL Express bring LocalDB? Aka the one installed by Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry, i meant your localhost version - had SQL Express in my brain from other things at the time.